# What torque can the human wrist take?

Tags: human-physiology, joints

Say you are holding a rod in one hand with your tumb on one side and the rest of your fingers on the other. What amount of torque could be exerted onto the rod (with the axis of rotation being around your forearm) before the average person's wrist starts to hurt?
I am asking this because from my calculations it seems like mine can withstand 115Nm which seems unreasonably high. On top of that all studies I can find only measure with the axis of rotation in line with the rod itself.
I hope you guys can help me out, thanks for the effort beforehand.

Comment: "...before the average person's wrist starts to hurt?" There is no "average" person (imo); there are males and females, there are various ranges of mobility due to hormones or genetics, there is well developed and poorly developed musculature and connective tissue and everything in between, etc. There *are* averages in a group of similar individuals, e.g. '30 y.o. white males in good health'. Averages don't really mean that much when it comes to one individual's characteristics. (I know it sounds nit-picky, but it's true.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse, that seems fair, but what kind of range can I expect it to be in? Because the 115Nm that I got don't *seem* plausible.

Comment: TBH, I don't know. Speaking medically (where most of my expertise lies), it doesn't matter. I can imagine how stupid that sounds, but it's true. I do think an orthopedist or a physiatrist can answer that with some authority, but I don't think we have one on this site. Sorry to be of so little service.

Comment: The technical terms you should include in literature search are "pronation" and "supination". [This article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/11256668_Upper-limb_surface_electro-myography_at_maximum_supination_and_pronation_torques_The_effect_of_elbow_and_forearm_angle) seems to measure exactly this. Also, please let us know how you derived your estimate of 115 Nm. You might have made a (trivial) mistake somewhere.

Comment: @Domen - Those are extremes before damage occurs; the OP just wants to know at which point it will start to hurt.